# Do not know how to open a gedit back-up file, would appreciate some help

Tags: files, backup, gedit

I was a user of ubuntu 8 or whatnot a couple of years ago,nowadays I've been working with Ubuntu 14.04 for some time and I've picked up the habit of putting my thoughts into a simple gedit document. However, as the system tends to crash every once in a while for absolutely no good reason (Toshiba is one, though), I often forget to save the document before I am forced to restart the computer. I can see the back up file right below the original one, yet when I try to open it it will try to find a program to do it, yet quite unsuccessfully. Is there anyone out there who can help me, por favor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gedit itself is used to open backup files .
 Right click on file open with gedit
Or
 Open terminal to that path and type

```
gedit filename
```

(filename that ends with ~)
If u forget to save file i recommend to turn on autosave after every x min in preference option of gedit

Comment: Thanks, I should have thought of it, this was definitely not a problem worthy of mentioning...

Comment: Yes.. consider accepting as solution if it helps! And mark it green checkmark√